# How to conduct nested named entity recognition in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am currently working on a java web server project, that requires the use of Natural Language processing, specifically **Named Entity Recognition** (**NER**).

I was using OpenNLP for java, since it was easy to add custom training data. It works perfectly.

However, I need to also be able to extract entites inside of entities (**Nested named entity recognition**). I tried doing this in OpenNLP, but I got parsing errors. So my guess is that OpenNLP sadly does not support nested entities.

Here is an example of what I need to parse:

Remind me to **[START:reminder]** give some presents to **[START:contact]** John **[END]** and **[START:contact]** Charlie **[END][END]**.

If this cannot be achieved with OpenNLP, is there any other Java NLP Library that could do this. If there are no Java libraries at all, are there any NLP libraries in any other language that can do this?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried just training for both? instead of nesting them, just maintain two different models.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

1. This cannot be achieved using openNLP NER which is suitable only for continuous entities because it use a [BIO](https://web.archive.org/web/20170805150451/https://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/) tagging scheme.
2. I don't know any library in any language capable of do this.

I think you are extending too much the concept of entity, which is habitually associated with persons, places, organizations, gene names etc.
But not with the identification of complex structures within text.

For that purpose you need to think in a more elaborated solution, taking into account the grammatical structure of the sentence, which can be obtained using a parser like the one in [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.parser), and maybe combine this with the output of the NER process.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of Name Entity Recognition (Java based) I use the following:

1. Apache UIMA
2. ClearTK

https://github.com/merishav/cleartk-tutorials

You can train models for your use case, I have already trained for NER for person, places, date of birth, profession.
ClearTK gives you a wrapper on MalletCRFClassifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use this python source code (Python 3) https://gist.github.com/ttpro1995/cd8c60cfc72416a02713bb93dff9ae6f

It's create multiple un-nest version of nest data for you.

For input sentence below ( input data must be tokenized first, so there are space between  and thing around it)

```
Remind me to <START:reminder> give some presents to <START:contact> John <END> and <START:contact> Charlie <END> <END> .
```

It output multiple sentence with different nest level.

```
Remind me to give some presents to John and Charlie .
Remind me to <START:reminder> give some presents to John and Charlie <END> .
Remind me to give some presents to <START:contact> John <END> and <START:contact> Charlie <END> .
```

Full source code here for quick copy-paste

```
import sys

END_TAG = 0
START_TAG = 1
NOT_TAG = -1

def detect_tag(in_token):
    """
    detect tag in token
    :param in_token:
    :return:
    """
    if "<START:" in in_token:
        return START_TAG
    elif "<END>" == in_token:
        return END_TAG

    return NOT_TAG

def remove_nest_tag(in_str):
    """
    với <START:ORGANIZATION> Sở Cảnh sát Phòng cháy , chữa cháy ( PCCC ) và cứu nạn , cứu hộ <START:LOCATION> Hà Nội <END> <END>
    :param in_str:
    :return:
    """
    state = 0
    taglist = []
    tag_dict = dict()
    sentence_token = in_str.split()
    ## detect token tag
    max_nest = 0

    for index, token in enumerate(sentence_token):
        # print(token + str(detect_tag(token)))
        tag = detect_tag(token)
        if tag > 0:
            state += 1
            if max_nest < state:
                max_nest = state
            token_info = (index, state, token)
            taglist.append(token_info)
            tag_dict[index] = token_info
        elif tag == 0:
            token_info = (index, state, token)
            taglist.append(token_info)
            tag_dict[index] = token_info
            state -= 1


    generate_sentences = []
    for state in range(max_nest+1):
        generate_sentence_token = []
        for index, token in enumerate(sentence_token):
            if detect_tag(token) >= 0: # is a tag
                token_info = tag_dict[index]
                if token_info[1] == state:
                    generate_sentence_token.append(token)
            elif detect_tag(token) == -1 : # not a tag
                generate_sentence_token.append(token)
        sentence = ' '.join(generate_sentence_token)
        generate_sentences.append(sentence)
    return generate_sentences


    # generate sentence
    print(taglist)

def test():
    tstr2 = "Remind me to <START:reminder> give some presents to <START:contact> John <END> and <START:contact> Charlie <END> <END> ."
    result = remove_nest_tag(tstr2)
    print("-----")
    for sentence in result:
        print(sentence)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    un-nest dataset for opennlp name
    """
    # test()
    # test()
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        inpath = sys.argv[1]
        infile = open(inpath, 'r')
        outfile = open(inpath+".out", 'w')
        for line in infile:
            sentences = remove_nest_tag(line)
            for sentence in sentences:
                outfile.write(sentence+"\n")
        outfile.close()
    else:
        print("usage: python unnest_data.py input.txt")
```